# My internal JavaScript for my Kelvin/Fahrenheit Converter is not working

Tags: javascript

I put my JavaScript inside  tags instead of externally(because external files weren't working) and for some reason my code is not running.

Just to be sure that it wasn't a problem with the code itself, I put a simple alert before all the code and nothing popped up.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Fahrenheit/Kelvin Converter</h1>
    <div id = "first" class = "oneof">
        <h2>Kelvin to Fahrenheit</h2>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Kelvin here" id = "kinput">
        <button id  = "ksubmit">Submit Kelvin</button><br><br>
        <textarea id = "fpopup" rows = "5" cols = "50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id = "second" class = "oneof">
        <h2>Fahrenheit to Kelvin</h2>
        <input type = "text" placeholder = "Enter Fahrenheit here" id = "finput">
        <button id  = "fsubmit">Submit Fahrenheit</button><br><br>
        <textarea id = "kpopup" rows = "5" cols = "50"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script>
      alert("Hello World"); //Testing JS
      if(6==6){
        alert("ua");
      }
      function ftok(f){
        k = (f − 32) * 5/9 + 273.15;
        return k;

      }
      function ktof(k){
        f = (K − 273.15) * 9/5 + 32;
        return f;

        
      }
      document.getElementById("ksubmit").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("fpopup").value = document.getElementById("kinput").value + " degrees Kelvin is "  + ktof(Number(document.getElementById("kinput").value)) + " degrees Fahrenheit"
      }
      document.getElementById("fsubmit").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("kpopup").value = document.getElementById("finput").value + " degrees Fahrenheit is "  + ftok(Number(document.getElementById("finput").value)) + " degrees Kelvin"
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using some weird Unicode character for multiplication: `×`. Instead, you should use an asterisk: `*`. If you open your browser's console you can see the error.

Comment: Oh ok I'll edit that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `DOMContentLoaded` function to make sure the HTML is ready and parsed properly. Also you have some `syntax` **errors** which i have fixed as well.

Also, You were using some weird `minus` and `multiplication` characters.

> The `DOMContentLoaded` event fires when the initial HTML document has been completely loaded and parsed

Your code is now working as expected.

**Live Demo:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Fahrenheit/Kelvin Converter</h1>
  <div id="first" class="oneof">
    <h2>Kelvin to Fahrenheit</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Kelvin here" id="kinput">
    <button id="ksubmit">Submit Kelvin</button><br><br>
    <textarea id="fpopup" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="second" class="oneof">
    <h2>Fahrenheit to Kelvin</h2>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Fahrenheit here" id="finput">
    <button id="fsubmit">Submit Fahrenheit</button><br><br>
    <textarea id="kpopup" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
  </div>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {

      if (6 == 6) {
        alert("ua");
      }

      function ftok(f) {
        var k = (f - 32) * 5 / 9 + 273.15;
        return k;

      }

      function ktof(k) {
        var f = (k - 273.15) * 9 / 5 + 32;
        return f;

      }
      document.getElementById("ksubmit").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("fpopup").value = document.getElementById("kinput").value + " degrees Kelvin is " + ktof(Number(document.getElementById("kinput").value)) + " degrees Fahrenheit"
      }
      document.getElementById("fsubmit").onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("kpopup").value = document.getElementById("finput").value + " degrees Fahrenheit is " + ftok(Number(document.getElementById("finput").value)) + " degrees Kelvin"
      }

    })
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```